# Error en creación de tablas SQL Server: "Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'DATABASE"

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, tablas

Al ejecutar el siguiente código para crear una base de datos y sus tablas me sale el error **"Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'DATABASE"**

```
CREATE DATABASE JOIN_EJEMPLOS

USE DATABASE JOINEJEMPLOS

CREATE TABLE PERSONA (
ID_PERSONA INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY,
NOMBRE_PERSONA VARCHAR(30),
APELLIDO_PERSONA VARCHAR(30),
ID_ESTADO INT FOREIGN KEY (ID_ESTADO) REFERENCES ESTADO (ID_ESTADO)
)

CREATE TABLE ESTADO (
ID_ESTADO INT PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBRE_ESTADO VARCHAR(30)
)
USE JOINEJEMPLOS
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pareciera que simplemente el tema es que creaste la base `JOIN_EJEMPLOS` y luego estás tratando de usar la base `JOINEJEMPLOS`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese código tiene varios problemas:

- El comando `USE` no necesita la palabra `DATABASE`
- El nombre de la base de datos no es correcto, falta un guion bajo.
- No se puede crear una referencia de llave foranea a una tabla que no ha sido creada.

Answer (score 1):

utiliza

```
USE JOIN_EJEMPLOS
```

la palabra DATABASE no es necesaria

Comment: ¿Por qué se tiene que hacer esto?

Comment: Hola @MarcosRedondo, aunque esta respuesta puede servir de guía para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, la respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir más detalle. Lee [answer] y visita el [tour] para más información.